Build a pre-decorated class with override_settings for faster client.login?
This makes a Django test using the test client run very much faster, where login security is not an important part of the test
from django.test import TestCase, Client, override_settings

@override_settings(
    PASSWORD_HASHERS = [ "django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher"  ])
class Test2(TestCase):
    ...

Is there any way to create my own TestCase subclass with the decorator built in, so I can code like this? (I keep having to look up that setting to override  when I find my new test running slow! )
from myproject.utils import FastLoginTestCase

class Test2( FastLoginTestCase):
    ...


I'm not sure that is possible directly, you may need to write a metaclass yourself. Why not just create your own decorator fast_login = override_settings(...) for reusability and then @fast_login class Test2(TestCase): ...?

You can apply the decorator to a subclass in an __init_subclass__ method:
class FastLoginTestCase(TestCase):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        override_settings(
            PASSWORD_HASHERS = ["django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher"]
        )(cls)


Thanks. Works perfectly. I know there had to be a way!

You cannot replace cls in __init_subclass__ - please remove cls assignment from this, it's extremely misleading. It works because override_settings modifies class in-place (see first Note here), but your assignment makes it look like cls is actually replaced.
